# UnknownHostException on Android Devices whereas it is working on IOS Devices

Tags: android, ios, url, mobile, unknown-host

I am getting UnknownhostException on android application whereas same URL is working on Chrome browser of my android mobile device and on IOS application as well.

Unable to understand the cause of it.

Comment: Check your internet connection

Comment: Connection is stable

Comment: Can you add log here?